# How to display interactive plot spyder python 3.5.2

Tags: python, plot, interactive, spyder

i wanted to to have 3d plot were the z values change every second and the change is displayed in the plot.
And it works...kinda. Only the very last plot is actually shown. Before that the Figure just stays blank. I thought it had to do with my script. But then I used a working example from the rawspberry website with exactly the same result. Blank window, after script is done the last actually gets displayed.
I can't find any working solution for this problem so far.

Here is the code of the example from the rwaspberry website:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from time import sleep
    from random import shuffle

    plt.ion()

    y = [i for i in range(100)]
    x = [i for i in range(len(y))]

    for i in range(50):
        plt.clf()
        plt.bar(x,y)
        plt.draw()
        sleep(0.5)
        shuffle(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `plt.pause()` instead of `sleep()`

```
for i in range(50):
    plt.clf()
    plt.bar(x,y)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.5)
    shuffle(y)
```